# Задача из Керниган-Ритчи

Tags: c, массивы

Выполнял задание из Керниган&Ритчи. "Напишите программу для вывода гистограммы длинн слов во входном потоке"

Пишу пока для горизонтальных "линий". Но несмотря на мои старания, программа считывает пробелы, и инкрементирует указатель массива при указанном на то запрете 
        '(state == out)'
Ниже прилагаю код. Компиллятор - minGW, IDE - Dev-C++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

#define     in  0
#define     out 1
main() {

    char c;
    int i,state,length;
    int nword[20];       // Массив значений длинн слов
    c = i = length = 0;
    state = out;          //Положение курсора (внутри или снаружи слова)


    printf("Please input text\n");

    for ( i = 0 ; i<=19; ++i){
        nword[i]=0;
    }

    i=0;
    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) {

        if ((c != '\n') || (c != '\t')||(c != ' ')){        // Если принятый символ не является символом форматирования
            if (state == in) {
            ++length;
            }

            else    {
                    state = in;
                    }
        }
        if ( (c == '\n') || (c == '\t') || (c == ' ') )     {       // Если принятый символ является символом форматирования
            if (state == in) {
                state = out;
                nword[i] = length;
                length = 0;
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i=0;i<=19;++i){
        printf ("%2d     ", i);
        printf ("%2d  ", c=nword[i]);
        for (c = nword[i]; c > 0; --c){
            printf("* ");
        }
            printf("\n");
        }
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## (To be or not to be) = true

Вот это ваше условие `((c != '\n') || (c != '\t')||(c != ' '))` - тавтология, которая всегда истинна.

Comment: Да. Действительно. Не подумавши записал именно так. Спасибо. С этим исправлением все заработало. Сейчас ещё разберусь что происходило в прошлом варианте программы, и буду писать вертикальные гистограммы.